# Batch class not executing

Tags: batch

I have written a simple batch class to update a field.

Here is my code:

```
global class batchCaseUpdate implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        String query = 'SELECT Id,LastChatterPostDate__c,No_of_Days_Case_Untchd_Business_Days__c FROM Case WHERE (Status = "In Progress")';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);

    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Case> scope) {

         for(Case c : scope)
         {
             String BusinessHours_Id;

             Long  Mins_since_lastTouched = BusinessHours.diff (BusinessHours_Id, c.LastChatterPostDate__c, System.Now()) / 1000 / 60;
             c.No_of_Days_Case_Untchd_Business_Days__c = Mins_since_lastTouched / 24 / 60;

         }
         update scope;
    }   

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    }
}
```

When i am executing the above batch class, it is not executing. 
Please can some one suggest me where the fault is?

BR

Comment: How do you know if it executes or not? add system.debug(""); message inside the execute method to see.

Comment: Are you seeing that this Batch class is not being executed through a test class? If you have a test class, can you please provide it here.

Comment: got the below error, when checked from logs. Error:   no viable alternative at character "" at line 4 column 1

Answer (score 1):

Try below code: SOQL query was not correct. Added the escape character that will run the query as expected.

```
global class batchCaseUpdate implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
  global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    String query = 'SELECT Id,LastChatterPostDate__c,No_of_Days_Case_Untchd_Business_Days__c FROM Case WHERE Status = \'In Progress\'';
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);

  }

  global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Case> scope) {

     for(Case c : scope)
     {
         String BusinessHours_Id;

         Long  Mins_since_lastTouched = BusinessHours.diff (BusinessHours_Id, c.LastChatterPostDate__c, System.Now()) / 1000 / 60;
         c.No_of_Days_Case_Untchd_Business_Days__c = Mins_since_lastTouched / 24 / 60;

     }
     update scope;
  }   

  global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
  }
}
```

Comment: How to exscape if i have multiple conditions in SOQL like....                 String query = 'SELECT Id,LastChatterPostDate__c,No_of_Days_Case_Untchd_Business_Days__c FROM Case WHERE Status = In Progress || Status = New || Status = Assigned. Thanks for the earlier sugestion.

Comment: Put the condition in Or clause like Status = \'In Progress\' OR Status = \'New\' likewise for all the condition that you want.

Comment: 'SELECT Id,LastChatterPostDate__c,No_of_Days_Case_Untchd_Business_Days__c FROM Case WHERE Status = \'In Progress\' || Status = \'New\' || Status =\' Assigned\''

Comment: No you need to specify OR and not ||

Comment: 'SELECT Id,LastChatterPostDate__c,No_of_Days_Case_Untchd_Business_Da‌​ys__c FROM Case WHERE Status = \'In Progress\' OR Status = \'New\' OR Status =\' Assigned\''

Comment: Mark the answer as done if you have completed the task

Comment: The batch class has been saved, however when executing this form developer console, the relative records are not being updated.

Comment: try to debug the value that you are trying to update see if the value is correctly populated. or else create a new List<Case> caseListToUpdate put the value in the list once you assign and finally update caseListToUpdate.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your line no 3 with the below code.Do let me know if this works or not

```
String Status = 'In Progress';
String query = 'SELECT Id,LastChatterPostDate__c,No_of_Days_Case_Untchd_Business_Days__c FROM Case WHERE Status = ' +Status ;
```

OR

```
String query = 'SELECT Id,LastChatterPostDate__c,No_of_Days_Case_Untchd_Business_Days__c FROM Case WHERE Status = \'In Progress\'';
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation example leads people to use dynamic SOQL when static SOQL is almost always the better choice:

```
public class batchCaseUpdate implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([
                SELECT Id, LastChatterPostDate__c, No_of_Days_Case_Untchd_Business_Days__c
                FROM Case
                WHERE (Status = 'In Progress')
                ]);
    }
    ...
```

because:

- the code is clearer (less noise)
- the query can be easily laid out over multiple lines so the logic is visible without having to scroll over to the right
- quotes don't need escaping
- the compiler checks the query
- if binding is needed, allows the use of complex binding expressions whereas dynamic Apex only supports simple binding expressions

Also note that `public` not `global` is usually the appropriate access modifier.